# Post-generate-script for Maven archetype is not working in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, groovy, maven-archetype

Hello Everyone i got a strange error while generating a project from archetype .

There is a postscript groovy file archetype-post-generate.groovy(in archetype project) which is supposed to runs after any project gets created from that archetype .

This works fine if i am creating a project from cmd using mvn archetype:generate

However,the same script is not getting run  if i am creating project in eclipse using the same archetype

Do anyone have a solution for it ?

Comment: What process/plugin normally executes the Groovy script at the end of the archetype application process?  Eclipse may need an m2e extension to handle the same execution/goal.

Comment: Hello,   generate goal of maven-archetype-plugin does that .In the documentation it's written that if there is a  archetype-post-generate.groovy script present in the location , the it will execute it after the project is created from the archetype .

Comment: Looks like eclipse does not embed a new enough version of maven-archetype-plugin: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=514993

Comment: The m2e issue tracker moved to GitHub, the issue is now https://github.com/eclipse-m2e/m2e-core/issues/249